# Check if Hulu is Playing in Applescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I use BetterTouchTool to run Applescripts on my Macbook Pro touch bar to navigate Netflix and YouTube. I just subscribed to Hulu, so I'm trying to make the scripts work for that as well. I know how to pause the player—I tell the tab Hulu is playing in to run this Javascript:

```
execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('controls__playback-button keep-mouse-active controls__playback-button--playing')[0].click()"
```

Resuming is similar:

```
execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('controls__playback-button keep-mouse-active controls__playback-button--paused')[0].click()"
```

What I need to do is check whether or not Hulu is currently playing video. I'm not familiar with Javascript or HTML, but what I think I need to do is use

```
set huluState to execute javascript "xyz"
```

to check if the "PLAY" thingy is there in this class in the Hulu Player:

```
<div class="controls__playback-button-playing-tip button-tool-tips">PLAY</div>
```

Then I would use

```
if huluState = "PLAY" then
    return "Playing"
else if huluState = "PAUSE" then
    return "Paused"
end if
```

to determine what shows up on the BTT button and a similar snippet of code to either play or pause.

TL;DR: I need to get the "PLAY" or "PAUSE" from the class within the Hulu player with Javascript.